# Is there a template/constexpr/C++11 way of replacing X-macros?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

Is there a way to replace the [Xmacro](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros) idiom using C++11 features, and preferably not using the preprocessor? I was thinking tuple templates could be used, but I'm still trying to grok how those work.

Comment: +1 for alerting me to the fact that this technique has a name. I've seen it before in code and I've used it. But I didn't know it was named something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XMacros are a general tool for doing a *wide* variety of things. Many of which (such as creating a list of enumerators, strings, etc) are well beyond the capabilities of templates of any kind.

There are probably some cases that you might find a way to replace with templates. But certainly not all of them.

Comment: I was expecting that to be the case. The "some cases" that I'm using at the moment, and would like to replace with templates is stringifying enums.

Comment: @Naddiseo: For that case, absolutely not. Templates have no ability to transform a token into the string representation of that token, which is what that would require.

Comment: C++11 could really use some more powerful compile-time string processing and reflection capabilities. Something like `std::enum_name<Enum_type>::value() -> const char*` would be glorious.

Comment: I think you can write a constexpr constructor for a user defined literal, which would let you be able to pass strings as template parameters, so you might be able to build your own enum-like construct w/ different syntax that automatically does stringifying. (But even just normal accessing of the enum elements would involve quoting)